# sql server 2008 r2 - deny create and drop database but allow everything else

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, security

I want to create a new user 'user1' that will be able to see all databases and all tables and also execute SQL statement, procedures etc.

The only thing that I want to deny is creating/dropping or change database (rename, change properties, create new database or drop existing database).

How can I do it?

Comment: Unless you *give* a user that right, he/she won't be able to modify the databases. If you want to give them blanket read/write privileges, grant them the db_datareader/db_datawriter roles for each database

Comment: In case that a new database will be created in the future the user should have also access to select/insert/delete etc. to the new database as well. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @user436862 When adding a new database, the existing user's login should have a user mapping added for that new database and given the db_datareader + db_datawriter permissions in the user mappings. If you have already done this for another database, you can get SQL management studio to generate a script for the login to make this easier to automate for other databases or a list of databases.

Comment: @user436862 *database-level* permissions can only be applied per database. You may be able to use a server-scoped trigger to assign the role to new databases eg `CREATE TRIGGER ddl_give_access
ON ALL SERVER 
FOR CREATE_DATABASE 
AS ...`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a dev server, I find it easiest to create a role in MODEL database that has all the right mix of privileges and then assign that role to a user mapped to a login that you need. When you create a new database that user will automatically be assigned privileges to that database.

Two caveats here: that login must be present on the server or else you will not be able to create a new database. Another important one is that the user will have completely unnecessary privileges to read and write to model database by default - definitely NOT a good idea on a production server. On a production server just create the role in model database, but only create user for the databases that you need.

This is the script you can use to create the role:

```
USE [model]
GO
CREATE ROLE [db_data_read_write_execute] AUTHORIZATION [db_securityadmin]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [db_data_read_write_execute]
GRANT EXECUTE to [db_data_read_write_execute]
GO
CREATE USER [DML_Only_User] FOR LOGIN [DML_Only_User_Login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO 
ALTER ROLE [db_data_read_write_execute] ADD MEMBER [DML_Only_User]
```

Comment: why the line "ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [db_data_read_write_execute]" been called twice?

Comment: No idea.  Copy-paste error, most likely, or some auto-scripting glitch. Updated the script now.